# Adding WindowsFormsHost throws XamlParseException

Tags: wpf, f#, windowsformshost, fsxaml

I was trying to add a Line Chart using `FSharp.Charting` in `MainWindow`. In MainViewModel I have -

```
let chart = Chart.Line [ for i in 0 .. 10 -> (i, i * i) ]
let control = new ChartControl(chart)
member self.LineChart = control
```

and in xaml -

```
<WindowsFormsHost Child="{Binding LineChart}" />
```

When I start the application, I get `XamlParseException` with following additional information -

```
'Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}WindowsFormsHost'.' Line number '20' and line position '10'.
```

How to solve the problem?

---

Here it is @Foggy Finder. I have removed few lines defining TextBlock and Buttons.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"   
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"   
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewModels;assembly=AsyncFS"
xmlns:fsxaml="http://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml"
Title="MVVM and XAML Type provider" Height="200" Width="400">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WindowsFormsHost Child="{Binding LineChart}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why not use `OxyPlot` or `LiveCharts`?

Comment: Can you show full XAML (or at least its title) ?

Comment: `FSharpCharting` seems easier than `LiveChart`. I am not yet familiar with OxyPlot` @FoggyFinder

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant for this Q but [windowsformshost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382234/adding-windowsformshost-control-to-mainwindow-causes-to-crash-the-exe/) has some sample code. I have added in the past FSharp Charts to WPF. It flickers a lot, you will be better of using native WPF like oxyplot or livecharts.

Comment: @s952163 livechart did not render bars at all for some volume of stock trade in one of my C# Test project where DevExpress chart worked fine. livechart's animation is better than that of devexpress. In case of small and medium sized array I will use livechart.

Comment: @EmonHaque yes, I wouldn't be surprised if you come across some bugs there, I only tested so can't comment much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `WinfowsFormsHost` you need to add a reference to `WindowsFormsIntegration`. But if you do it you get :

> A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Child' property of type
>   'WindowsFormsHost'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a
>   DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Easy way to fix is to create the object directly:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding LineChart}" />
```

...

```
member self.LineChart = new WindowsFormsHost(Child = control)
```

Result:

[image]